# javascript: problem assigning indexes of array within array, with if statement in a loop

Tags: javascript

Given str="GC" I need an output of:
[ [ 'G', 'C' ], [ 'C', 'G' ] ]
My code below seems to run the first if statement, create the first entry for the "G":
[["G" "C"]]
But then when the second iteration ("C"), which runs the else if, it converts both to
[ [ 'C', 'G' ], [ 'C', 'G' ] ]

I don't understand, the values I assign in the first if statement are overwritten, and I don't understand why.

```
function pairElement(str) {
  let a = []
  let b = []

  for (let i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    a[i]=b
    if (str[i]=="G") {
      console.log("case 1")
      a[i][0]="G"
      a[i][1]="C"
      console.log(a)
    }
    else if (str[i]=="C") {
      console.log("case 2")
      a[i][0]="C"
      a[i][1]="G"
      console.log(a)
    }
  }

  return a;
}

console.log(pairElement("GC")); //desired output: [ [ 'G', 'C' ], [ 'C', 'G' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `b` value before the loop and that what is cosing the problem:
Just create it inside the loop and you should get your desired result.

```js
function pairElement(str) {
  let a = []
  

  for (let i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
 let b = [];
    a[i] = b;
    if (str[i]=="G") {
      console.log("case 1")
      a[i][0]="G"
      a[i][1]="C"
      console.log(a)
    }
    else if (str[i]=="C") {
      console.log("case 2")
      a[i][0]="C"
      a[i][1]="G"
      console.log(a)
    }
  }

  return a;
}

console.log(pairElement("GC"));
```

Comment: Why is that? I'm looking at it and I don't see 'b' being assigned to a new value within the for loop....so why is it putting it inside fixing things...? I'm missing something still.

Comment: Okay I see it is updating b within the for loop..where is it doing this tho...?

Comment: When you are creating `b` outside the loop, you are basicly reassing its values inside the loop. In the first iteration `i=0` -> `b = ['G','C']`, but on the second iteration `i=1` yoy are reassigning it to `b=['C','G']`

Comment: Oh nvm I see now....cause its an array the a[i]=b is updating the original b as well cause it's referencing the same data.

Comment: Yep, and when `b` is created inside the loop you are creating new object.